# html/javascript canvas drawImage without 2times loading

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to place an image in a HTML5 canvas. I found some sample code which worked, but the image was loaded 2 times when I actually only need 1. I can hide one of the images with JavaScript or CSS, but I'm looking for a way where the image only needs to load once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img id="img" src="img.png" width="150px" height="150px">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only see the image displayed once when I use the code above under the <img> element. The canvas element is empty and does not contain the image at the moment. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image's drawn twice, because you create `<img../>` node first and then redraw it to the canvas.

Just remove `<img id="img" src="img.png" width="150px" height="150px">` and add this to your JavaScript code:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = 'img.png';
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image's drawn twice, because you create  node first and then redraw it to the canvas. 
 but using above code image can not be scale fit 
use this below code to draw the image on canvas with responsive to canvas

```
<div id="worldmap" style="height=100%;width=100%">
    <canvas id="myStaticMap"></canvas>
<div>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myStaticMap"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = $("#worldmap").width();
canvas.height = $("#worldmap").height();

ctx.drawImage(mapImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```